# Why we inject parameter inside array and function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm a beginner in Angular development. I don't know why we inject twice argument inside for controller like:

```
app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', 'myFactory', 'Myothers', function ($scope, myFactory, Myothers) {}])
```

and see

```
app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, myFactory, Myothers) {})
```

Could you explain why we do this?

Comment: Its for minification. Angular hacks up named arguments by inferring the service you want from the variable name. When you minify your code your arguments get renamed. So when angular runs it can't find the correct services. This allows you to minify your code and angular still know which service your trying to inject.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation).

Comment: @ste2425, I'm having an issue trying to inject parameters into an inline controller function. Any chance you could take a look at [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930202/having-trouble-properly-injecting-parameters-into-inline-controller-function-in)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is to protect the code from javascript minification.

The `$inject` makes sure that the variable names are preserved in the form of strings.

So ideally your app code should look something like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('YourApp', []);
 var appCtrl = app.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

 appCtrl.$inject = ['dep1', 'dep2']; //add all the dependencies

 function AppCtrl (dep1,dep2){  //add the name of the dependencies here too
    //your controller logic
 }
```

During minification javascript replaces variable name with custom names, so `dep1` might be replaced by `d` and hence will cause error.

But `$inject` will let angular know that the actual name of the dependency is `dep1` as it is stored in the form of `string` value which is protected from minification.

Hence we use `$inject`.

Answer (score 3):

first you can do without array like:

```
app.controller("myController",function($scope,myFactory,MyOrders){});
```

in array you are declares variables , you can do like something that:

```
app.controller('mycontroller',['$scope', 'myFactory', 'Myothers', function (s, f, o) {}])
```

the s as scope , the f as myfactory , the o as order;

it is your's choice how to use , but in angular tutorials they say the right way is :

```
app.controller('mycontroller',['$scope', 'myFactory', 'Myothers', function (s, f, o) {}])
```

Answer (score 2):

When we pass a dependency as an **`Array`** Argument, the application does not break in production when we **`minify`** the application.

**Ways to do this :**

- Using the Named function
- Using the Inline Anonymous function

**Using the Named function :**

We can pass dependencies as Array Arguments with the named function.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.name = "Rohit";

};

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', MyCtrl]);
```

**Using the Inline Anonymous function :**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = "Rohit";

}]);
```

**Differences :**

The difference is that when the `app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, myFactory, Myothers) {})` is minified, the parameter name will be minified and angular will no longer be able to figure out which dependencies to inject. The `array` syntax with the dependency in a string means that it is `minification` safe.

**alternate solution :**

we can use `ng-annotate` library which will change the `app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, myFactory, Myothers) {})` into the `app.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', 'myFactory', 'Myothers', function ($scope, myFactory, Myothers) {}])` so that the code is again `minification` safe.